# Change base url in manthan marketplace extension in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I use manthan marketplace extension in my store and it show the base url for each
shop like this: `domain-name/seller/sellershopname`

I should change and replace '**seller**' in url with '**producers**'... how can I do this?
(without rewrite)

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Manthan_Marketplace>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </Manthan_Marketplace>
</modules> 
<global>
    <models>
        <marketplace>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>marketplace_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </marketplace>
        <marketplace_mysql4>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <seller>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_seller</table>
                </seller>
                <vendorproduct>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_vendorproduct</table>
                </vendorproduct>
                <review>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_review</table>
                </review>
                <rating>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_rating</table>
                </rating>
                <sellerrate>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_seller_rated</table>
                </sellerrate>
                <payment>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_payment</table>
                </payment>
            </entities>
        </marketplace_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <marketplace_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Manthan_Marketplace</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </marketplace_setup>
        <marketplace_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </marketplace_write>
        <marketplace_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </marketplace_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <marketplace>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Block</class>
        </marketplace>
        <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                   <product_list>Manthan_Marketplace_Block_Seller_Catalog_Product_List</product_list>
              </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_item_renderer_default>Manthan_Marketplace_Block_Sales_Order_Item_Renderer_Default</order_item_renderer_default>
                <order_item_renderer_grouped>Manthan_Marketplace_Block_Sales_Order_Item_Renderer_Grouped</order_item_renderer_grouped>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <system_account_edit_form>Manthan_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_System_Account_Edit_Form</system_account_edit_form>
            </rewrite>
             <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_grid>Manthan_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <marketplace>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Helper</class>
        </marketplace>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>sellerOperationAfterOrderSuccess</method>
                </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
            <observers>
                <manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>addSellerInfo</method>
                </manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
        <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            <observers>
                <manthan_marketplace_sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>saveSellerToOrderItem</method>
                </manthan_marketplace_sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            </observers>
        </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
            <observers>
                <manthan_marketplace_controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>dynamicSellerLink</method>
                </manthan_marketplace_controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
    </events>
     <template>
        <email>
            <marketplace_vendor_registration_email_email_template module="marketplace">
                <label>New Seller Register</label>
                <file>marketplace/seller_new_registration_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </marketplace_vendor_registration_email_email_template>
            <marketplace_vendor_activation_email_email_template module="marketplace">
                <label>Seller Status Changed</label>
                <file>marketplace/seller_activation_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </marketplace_vendor_activation_email_email_template>
            <marketplace_email_email_template module="marketplace">
                <label>Seller New Order</label>
                <file>sales/seller_new_order.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </marketplace_email_email_template>
            <marketplace_registration_confirmation_email_email_template module="marketplace">
                <label>New Seller Confirmed</label>
                <file>marketplace/seller_confirmation_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </marketplace_registration_confirmation_email_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
<default>
   <web>
     <routers>
        <producers>
            <area>frontend</area>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Controller_Router</class>
        </producers>
    </routers>
   </web>
</default>  
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <marketplace>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Manthan_Marketplace</module>
                <frontName>marketplace</frontName>
            </args>
        </marketplace>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <marketplace>
                <file>marketplace.xml</file>
            </marketplace>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <marketplace>
                <files>
                    <default>Manthan_Marketplace.csv</default>
                </files>
            </marketplace>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <admin_marketplace>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Manthan_Marketplace</module>
                <frontName>admin_marketplace</frontName>
            </args>
        </admin_marketplace>
         <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Manthan_Marketplace before="Mage_Adminhtml">Manthan_Marketplace_Adminhtml_Admin</Manthan_Marketplace>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <marketplace>
                <file>marketplace.xml</file>
            </marketplace>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <marketplace>
                <files>
                    <default>Manthan_Marketplace.csv</default>
                </files>
            </marketplace>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductSaveAfter</method>
                </manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_save_after>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
        <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
          <observers>
            <manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_collection_load_before>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>marketplace/observer</class>
              <method>customFilterProductCollection</method>
            </manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_collection_load_before>
          </observers>
        </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
            <observers>
                <module_block_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>checkPermissionRole</method>
                </module_block_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
        <catalog_product_delete_before>
            <observers>
                <manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_delete_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductDeleteBefore</method>
                </manthan_marketplace_catalog_product_delete_before>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_delete_before>
    </events>
    <menu>
        <manthan translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>فروشگاه ها</title>
            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
            <children>
                <marketplace>
                    <title>مدیریت هنرمندان</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <pending_product>
                            <title>محصولات در انتظار</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <action>adminhtml/catalog_product/index/product_status/1</action>
                        </pending_product>
                        <sellers>
                            <title>مدیریت فروشندگان</title>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_account</action>
                        </sellers>
                        <review>
                            <title>مدیریت نظرات</title>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_review</action>
                        </review>
                        <rating>
                            <title>Manage Ratings</title>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_rating</action>
                        </rating>
                        <payment>
                            <title>معاملات فروشندگان</title>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_payment</action>
                        </payment>
                        <configuration>
                            <title>Configuration</title>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/marketplace/</action>
                        </configuration>
                    </children>
                </marketplace>
            </children>
        </manthan>
        <seller_dashboard module="adminhtml">
                <title>Dashboard</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_dashboard</action>
        </seller_dashboard>
        <seller translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Sales</title>
            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            <children>
                <orders>
                    <title>Manage Orders</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_order</action>
                </orders>
                <review>
                    <title>Manage Reviews</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_review</action>
                </review>
                <payment>
                    <title>Seller Transaction</title>
                    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_marketplace/adminhtml_payment</action>
                </payment>
            </children>
        </seller>
    </menu>
     <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <seller_dashboard>
                        <title>Dashboard</title>
                    </seller_dashboard>
                    <seller>
                        <title>Seller</title>
                        <children>
                            <review>
                                <title>review</title>
                            </review>
                            <orders>
                                <title>Orders</title>
                            </orders>                               
                            <payment>
                                <title>Seller Transaction</title>
                            </payment>
                        </children>
                    </seller>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <marketplace>
                                        <title>Market Place Section</title>
                                    </marketplace>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
<default>
    <marketplace>
        <seller>
            <product_status>1</product_status>
            <link_label>Connect as Seller</link_label>
        </seller>
        <review>
            <per_page>12,24,36</per_page>
        </review>
         <email>
            <email_sender>sales</email_sender>
            <email_template>marketplace_email_email_template</email_template>
        </email>
        <vendor_registration_email>
            <email_template>marketplace_vendor_registration_email_email_template</email_template>
        </vendor_registration_email>
        <vendor_activation_email>
            <email_template>marketplace_vendor_activation_email_email_template</email_template>
        </vendor_activation_email>
        <registration_confirmation_email>
            <email_template>marketplace_registration_confirmation_email_email_template</email_template>
        </registration_confirmation_email>
    </marketplace>
</default>
```

config.xml of extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got solution from **Manthan Marketplace extension developer** .Extension developer has been given support for this change.

first navigate to following path `app/code/community/Manthan/Marketplace/Helper/Data.php`
and find `getShopUrl($url)` function and replace function by below function

```
public function getShopUrl($url)
    {
        $shopUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl()."producer". DS . $url ;
        return $shopUrl;
    }
```

And go to `app/code/community/Manthan/Marketplace/Controller/Router.php`
then go to line number 8 and replace by this code

```
if ($path[0] != 'producer')
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks to You !! It Worked Very Well !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Module's `config.xml` file. You can see **FrontName** of `routers`.

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <themodule>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>The_Module</module>
                <frontName>seller</frontName>
            </args>
        </themodule>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

instead of `<frontName>seller</frontName>` change it with **producers**..

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I cant find seller , I update question by config.xml

Comment: If there is any free support from that Extension Provider, then don't hesitate to contact them.